# How can I install a system with apt-get without ncurses configuration screens?

Tags: debian, apt, automated-install, preseed

I wrote a BASH script for doing an unattendend install on an ARM based Debian system. One of the packages being installed is samba.

I added

```
apt-get -y install samba
```

into my setup routine, but apt-get hangs due an ncurse configuration window for Samba workgroup.

How can I pass such windows? My script download the right smb.conf etc. after apt-get installed the packages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`-y` or `--assume-yes` really should do it. Apparently not. :)

I think the thing to do is to put the answer in to the `debconf` database before installing the package. Then it'll already know the answer and shouldn't prompt. There's an [example of doing that here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120718175613/http://www.muhuk.com/2010/05/how-to-install-mysql-with-fabric).

Comment: Hello, the problem is that is not an apt-get question like 'Install samba (needs more xx MB on disc)'. It's a special 'task' which runs due an apt-get install samba command. This command displays an GUI using ncurses and ask for (in this case) a workgroups name. It seemed I can't supress this dialog using the -y option.

Comment: Oh, right. See edited answer. :)

Comment: Thanks in advanced. I finally got this at google too ,) Thanks very much for the example. It helped me a lot.

Comment: That url no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

What you need should be described in `man 7 debconf` in the section Priorities. Another way is described in the Frontend section (noninteractive)

Comment: `No manual entry for debconf in section 7`

Comment: @PhilippLudwig Yes, there is. At least on Debian 10.

Answer (score 0):

Set the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` to `noninteractive`, e.g.:

```
sudo env DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y samba
```